# What is the difference between StartKoin and install(Koin) for ktor applications

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I am working on a ktor api and I am adding DI for the first time. I have seen things done two different ways and I couldn't find a way that they mean anything different. Is there something that Start does that install doesn't? Does it matter if you are using embeddedServer or EngineMain also?

Here is the module being installed just for context

```
val mainModule = module(createdAtStart = true) {
    // this creates a global kmongo client for our db
    factory { KMongo.createClient(System.getenv("MONGO_URI") ?: "") }
}
```

way 1:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused")
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {

    startKoin {
        modules(mainModule)
    }
}
```

way 2:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused")
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {

    install(Koin){
        modules(mainModule)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here's the main difference

```
**
 * Start a Koin Application as StandAlone
 */
fun startKoin(appDeclaration: KoinAppDeclaration): KoinApplication = KoinPlatformTools.defaultContext().startKoin(appDeclaration)
```

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/392682bc6ebe428952485a45eb13af06a79789eb/core/koin-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/koin/core/context/DefaultContextExt.kt

```
/**
     * Feature installation script
     */
    public fun install(pipeline: TPipeline, configure: TConfiguration.() -> Unit): TFeature
```

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvm/src/io/ktor/application/ApplicationFeature.kt

The `install` is picked from the ktor library
Which can be implemented different things
Where's the `startKoin` is from its own

Comment: can you please give some context of when you would use one vs the other?